# What is the name of the expression to send a file as a response via vert.x

Tags: kotlin, vert.x

Im trying to send a html response after a request was received with vert.x wirtten in kotlin

I think the problem lies in the path. But Im not sure (still learning)

```
fun main() {
    val vertx = Vertx.vertx()
    val router = Router.router(vertx)

    router.route("/")
        .handler(){ routingContext ->
            val response = routingContext.response()
            response
                .setChunked(true)
                .putHeader("content-type", "text/html")
                .write( "./static/index.html")
                .end()
        }

    vertx
        .createHttpServer()
        .requestHandler(router::accept)
        .listen(8090)
    }
```

The write call just sends ./static/index.html/ as a response to the browser, I would like to have my html file as a response.

Answer (score 0):

To send a whole file, use `sendFile` instead of `write`:

```
val response = routingContext.response()
response
    .setChunked(true)
    .putHeader("content-type", "text/html")
    .sendFile( "./static/index.html")
```